# Borrar doblones en una cadena de texto en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista

Debuto en Python. En mi editor de código este programa aparentemente funciona bien; pero al someterlo a los tests de validación en línea.

La debilidad de mi programa está en que, al suprimir los doblones, la longitud de la pieza musical varía, se vuelve dinámica, lo que me llevó a crear la variable `i < 500`; pero el nuevo problema que se genera está en el hecho de que, al modificar `len(pieza)` suprimiendo el primer doblón que aparece e igualando a cero la variable index `idx` tras cada supresión, `i` continúa aumentando hasta igualarse a 500.

A continuación la situación problémica:

---

Escuchar música puede ser muy agradable, pero cuando una pieza es realmente repetitiva, a veces te aburres un poco. Así que el profesor de composición musical del conservatorio decidió imponer una regla muy estricta: si él ve dos notas idénticas una al lado de la otra, ¡las borra a las dos! Y continúa borrando mientras haya dos notas iguales consecutivas.

Lo que tu programa debe hacer:
Las notas musicales están representadas por las letras 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' y 'g'.

Tu programa debe leer una sola línea de texto que represente la pieza musical (menos de 500 notas) y debe mostrar la versión de la canción "corregida" donde se hayan eliminado todos los duplicados, siempre que existan.

**Ejemplo de entrada**:

> baaabbacddc

**Salida**:

```
b
```

**Este es mi programa**:

```
notas_musicales = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
pieza = list(input())
idx = 0
i = -1

while i < 500:

    if idx < 0 or idx == len(pieza) - 1 or len(pieza) == 0:
    # Esta línea para evitar los errores de "out of range"
        break
    else:
        idx += 1

    if pieza[idx] == pieza[idx - 1]:
        del pieza[idx]
        del pieza[idx - 1]
        idx = 0 
    # Cada vez que se borra un doblón, recomenzamos a recorrer la lista de nuevo

    i += 1

for i in pieza:
    print(i, end="")
```

***Comentario***

En el ejemplo anterior, la eliminación de los doblones ocurre de la siguiente forma:

```
baaabbacddc
baaabbacc
babbacc
babba
baa
b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Había entendido inicialmente que debían borrarse las secuencias de letras iguales (ya fueran de 2, 3 ó más), pero tras una lectura más atenta y con el ejemplo proporcionado por el usuario parece que no, que sólo son las secuencias de 2 las que deben borrarse. Y que una vez borradas, la cadena resultante debe ser sometida al mismo proceso, hasta que ya no queden más "doblones".

Por tanto planteo un nuevo algoritmo:

```
1. Generar una lista de doblones posibles, que serán ["aa", "bb", "cc", etc]
2. Repetir hasta que la longitud de la pieza no se altere más:
   2.1 Para cada posible doblón de la lista de doblones:
       Sustituir en la pieza ese doblón por ""
```

Lo tengo implementado y va muy bien. Dime si necesitas que te dé la solución completa con código.

Comment: No lo he probado aún, pero estoy seguro que funcionará!

Answer (score 1):

Yo buscaría los resultados impares, es decir, si una nota se encuentra en la pieza un numero de veces impar, quiere decir ke pasa, ejemplo bbb = 3 veces. El número 3 es impar por lo que puedes asumir que eliminastes las otras 2 b. algo como esto:

```
notas_musicales = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
pieza = list(input())
result = ""

for i in notas_musicales:
    if pieza.count(i) %2 != 0:
        result += i
print(result)
```

Comment: El problema es que hay que eliminar las repeticiones contiguas. Una nota puede aparecer tres veces separada por otras notas. La pieza `ababab` no debe sufrir modificaciones, por ejemplo.

Comment: Ah ok, por casulidad el problema es de HackerRank? si es así pro favor mándame el link

Comment: No, el problema es de [http://www.france-ioi.org/algo/task.php?idChapter=656&iOrder=2&idCourse=2240&idTask=2240&sTab=task&sMessage=&iVisibility=0&iSubmissionId=0&sLanguage=es]